# How to keep an ODROID device connectable via adb?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, root-access, shell, bash

I'm using an [Odroid](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php) (rooted) device running Android 5.1.1 on a local network and I'd like to be able to control it via `adb`.

Currently I'm running this at startup:

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

This works initially, but I've noticed if works with one connection at a time.
If a connection is left open, a second connection won't work.
Even though adb says I'm connected, whenever I try to run any command I get an error:

```
> adb connect 192.168.0.33
connected to 192.168.0.33:5555
> adb shell date
error: device offline
```

What's the easiest to ensure adbd is accessible, even if a connection is left open/hanging by accident ?

I'm thinking about running a script that periodically restarts `adbd` but having a short interval
will be very frustrating as I'd need to constantly reconnect. Is there a way to check if a connection
is open, but hanging ? (no data has been received in a while ?)

Alternatively, would it be possible to close the previous connection if a new one is made automatically ?

How would one keep an odroid connectible via adb constantly (regardless of open connections ?)

Comment: No expert in adb, but I think simultaneous connections are disabled.

Comment: @DanBrown that's the issue I'm trying to deal with: I'd like to kick out the previous user if it's hogging the connection or something similar

Comment: try this script https://gist.github.com/christopherperry/3208109

Comment: That's a handy script, however it deals with connecting to multiple android devices from  one computer and running commands on each. My situation is sort of the reverse: I have multiple computers that may want to connect to the same android device, but I need a way to ensure the connection doesn't get blocked if one of these computers forgets to disconnect

Comment: Why not have one master computer, that you can teamviewer to do so? Either that, or write a script that executes adb close-server whenever you adb start somewhere else.

Comment: that's sort of what I'm trying to do, but adb close-server is done on the actual android device (restarting ```adbd```). if the adb connection is locked already, can't use a computer to connect and trigger the ```adbd``` restart

Comment: That's why teamviewer is the holy grail of this kind of thing. Just use it- you will be making life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the scope of the project at that time there were two measures that helped:

1. Installing [SSHelper](https://arachnoid.com/android/SSHelper/index.html) to add SSH support (can use SSH instead of adb and restart adb daemon in case it gets locked)
2. Hacky, but a background service could be used to periodically reset adb connections: this could cause trouble depenending on what commands need to run and for how long